# Make custom layout persisten

Tags: debian, xkb

I'm using Debian, and I created a custom keyboard layout which adds some German letters to the standard US layout. The layout should show up in the GUI configuration tools. Also, it would be great, if the layout would stay after OS upgrades.

What I am doing now (every step is done manually):

- Add the layout to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` as a partial layout of `us(basic)`
- Go to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/`
- Add the layout variant to both `base.xml` and `evdev.xml` under `us`-layout:

  ```
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>usde</name>
        <description>English (US, with German letters)</description>
      </configItem>
    </variant>
  ```
- Add the layout variant to both `base.lst` and `evdev.lst` under `!variant`:

  ```
    usde            us: English (US, with German letters)
  ```

So far, the layout is working and also appears in the GUI setup. However, I am not really sure, whether it is the proper way to add it to `xkb`.

Which is not working, is the OS upgrade. On upgrade, all the files get replaced, so I need to repeat the whole procedure. Is there a way to make my layout persistent to upgrades?

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, you can't.

[the-bazaar-with-landmines-or-how-to-extend-xkb-the-right-way](https://medium.com/@daniel.jozsef/the-bazaar-with-landmines-or-how-to-extend-xkb-the-right-way-b82de59a1f9a)

I recommand you to script your procedure.